# Odoo 8 - how to get field values of current active id or current model

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

How to access the fields of current form view if it is not yet save or in editing mode?

I tried getting the current active id but I cant get it.
In my .py

```
@api.one
def _check_butcher(self):
    prod_id = self.env.context.get('active_id')
    # logging.info("TEST \n TEST %s" % prod_id.can_butcher)
    logging.info("TEST \n TEST %s" % prod_id)
    return prod_id
```

In the terminal, it is printed None

Comment: How is `_check_butcher` function triggered?

Comment: First and foremost, I don't think that is an Odoo 8 method. `self` should have the fields and their values. Instead of `context.get` try `self.id` and see the output. Also as @Kenly said the way you trigger it also important.

Answer (score 0):

I dont work with version 8 so my answer propably won't be most accurate but i think you should look for CRUD in this Documentation https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/  for "default_get()"